# cordova div overflow scroll causing whole screen to scroll

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, ionic-framework, scroll

In my cordova/Ionic v1 app I have a table in a div - the div is a fixed height and the table needs to scroll vertically within the div.  It sort of works.

I can scroll the table vertically within the div but its also causing the whole screen to scroll.  How can I get the just the div/table to scroll without causing the whole screen to scroll?

```
<div id="eventHistory" class="clubSection clubSectionCard" style="height:500px;overflow:auto;" ng-show="!historyInfo">
  <div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bolder;">CHECKIN/REWARD HISTORY</div>
  <table ng-if="club.eventHistory.length > 0" style="width:100%;text-align:left;display:block;">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:7.5%;">#</th>
      <th style="width:25%;">DATE</th>
      <th ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==0" style="width:10%;">PTS</th>
      <th ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==0" style="width:55%;">REWARD</th>
      
      <th ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==1" style="width:35%;">SITE</th>
      <th ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==1" style="width:30%;">REWARD</th>
   </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="hist in club.eventHistory" id="history_{{hist.chID}}" style="height:25px;">
      <td style="width:7.5%;">{{hist.checkins}}</td>
      <td style="width:25%;">{{hist.chDate}}</td>
      <td ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==0" style="width:10%;">{{hist.points}}</td>     
      <td ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==0 && hist.rewards.length == 0" style="width:57.5%;"> - - - </td>
      <td ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==0 && hist.rwards.length > 0" style="width:57.5%;">
        <div ng-repeat="reward in hist.rewards">
          <div ng-click="openReward(reward);">
            <div ng-if="reward.awardGiven==0 && hist.awardExpired==true" style="color:black"><i class="icon ion-ios-minus" style="color:black;"></i> {{hist.awardName}}</div>
            <div ng-if="reward.awardGiven==0 && hist.awardExpired==false" style="color:red"><i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline" style="color:red;"></i> {{hist.awardName}}</div>
            <div ng-if="reward.awardGiven==1" style="color:green;"><i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark" style="color:green;"></i> {{hist.awardName}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==1" style="width:33.5%;">{{hist.clShortName}}</td>     
      <td ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==1 && hist.rewards.length == 0" style="width:33.5%;"> - - - </td>
      <td ng-if="club.ceMultiCheckin==1 && hist.rewards.length > 0" style="width:33.5%;">
        <div ng-repeat="reward in hist.rewards">
          <div ng-click="openReward(reward);">
            <div ng-if="reward.awardGiven==0 && hist.awardExpired==true" style="color:black"><i class="icon ion-ios-minus" style="color:black;"></i> {{hist.awardName}}</div>
            <div ng-if="reward.awardGiven==0 && hist.awardExpired==false" style="color:red"><i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline" style="color:red;"></i> {{hist.awardName}}</div>
            <div ng-if="reward.awardGiven==1" style="color:green;"><i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark" style="color:green;"></i> {{hist.awardName}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Also, while testing, everytime I try to scroll anything div or screen - I am constantly getting this warning/error - its really annoying, would love to know how to get rid of it.

```
ionic.bundle.js:5179 [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
<div id="eventHistory" style="height:350px;overflow:scroll;" ng-focus="divScroll(1);" ng-blur="divScroll(0);" ng-show="!historyInfo">
  <div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bolder;">CHECKIN/REWARD HISTORY</div>
  <table style="width:100%;text-align:left;display:block;">
  ...
  </table>
</div>
```

And in my controller, for the `divScroll` function:

```
  $scope.divScroll = function(x) {
    if (x == 0) {
      // restore page scrolling
      $ionicScrollDelegate.freezeScroll(false) ;
    } else {
      if ($scope.club.eventHistory.length > 12) {
        $ionicScrollDelegate.freezeScroll(true) ;
      }
    }
```

It works much cleaner than without the `divScroll` function, but I feel there is a better solution - hopefully someone else can contribute.